# Flink Sql - Row Over Aggregate - Emit strategy

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

The flink sql docs doesn't share any information about the emit strategy of row over aggregate queries.
I guess it has the same behaviour as the windowed aggregation.
Only the rows are emitted when a window is closed and not as soon as an event arrived.

I tested it, and it works this way.
But would like to confirm this and check with you all, if there is a way to do any kind of windowed aggregation as soon as an row appears that includes the row.

Regards,
Harish.

Answer (score 0):

The Flink Window TVF functions don't support early/late fires, while the old legacy group functions do. You can track this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-29692

The reason for not supporting this is because 'Early fire' would periodically sent intermediate result to downstream. The frequency to send intermediate result is based on processing time, even thought the window itself based on event time. It mixed up processing time semantics with the time attribute of Window.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that early fires is possibe in legacy group functions. Unfortunately they are being deprecated by flink in the favour of Window TVF functions. 
However, my question is about Row Over Aggregates, Does it use Windowing TVF underneath?